# python - subprocess.Popen() synax errors

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am trying to mirror the following shell command using subprocess.Popen():

```
echo "SELECT employeeid FROM Users WHERE samaccountname=${1};" | bsqldb -S mdw2k8sqlp02.dow.com -D PhoneBookClient -U PortManUser -P plum45\\torts -q
```

It currently looks like:

```
stdout = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "\"SELECT", "employeeid", "FROM", "Users", "WHERE", "samaccountname=${1};\"", "|", "bsqldb", "arg1etc"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in stdout.stdout.readlines():
    print line
```

It seems that this is wrong, it returns the following standard out:

```
"SELECT employeeid FROM Users WHERE samaccountname=${1};" | bsqldb arg1etc
```

Does anyone know where my syntax for subprocess.Popen() has gone wrong?

Comment: As a side note, in Python, you can use single quotes to avoid needing to escape double quotes. `"SELECT` is a lot more readable than `"\"SELECT"`, and it's the exact same string. (Unlike bash, there is no difference at all between the two forms in Python, except of course which kind of quotes don't need to be escaped.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to run a shell command without the shell. What happens is that you're passing all of those strings—including `"|"` and everything after is—as arguments to the `echo` command.

Just add `shell=True` to your call to fix that.

However, you almost definitely want to pass the command line as a string, instead of trying to guess at the list that will be joined back up into the string to pass to the shell.

Or, even better, don't use the shell, and instead pipe within Python. The docs have a nice section about [Replacing shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) (and all kinds of other things) with `subprocess` code.

But in your case, the thing you're trying to pipe is just `echo`, which is quite silly, since you already have exactly what `echo` would return, and can just feed it as the input to the second program.

Also, I'm not sure what you expect that `${1}` to get filled in with. Presumably you're porting a shell script that took some arguments on the command line; your Python script may have the same thing in `sys.argv[1]`, but without knowing more about what you're doing, that's little more than a guess.

Comment: I'm trying to build this on a production environment, it would be best if I could avoid 'shell=True'. Thanks for the link to piping with subprocess, that seems to be exactly what I need :)

Comment: @EvanDefend: It's really worth reading through the entire `subprocess` doc page. Some of the sections are reference stuff you can just skip over, but there's a whole lot of useful tutorial-ish information in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

The analog of `echo some string | command arg1 arg2` shell pipeline in Python is:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["command", "arg1", "arg2"], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate("some string")
```

In your case, you could write it as:

```
import shlex
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = shlex.split("bsqldb -S mdw2k8sqlp02.dow.com -D PhoneBookClient "
                  "-U PortManUser -P plum45\\torts -q")
sql = """SELECT employeeid FROM Users
         WHERE samaccountname={name};""".format(name=sql_escape(sys.argv[1]))
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input=sql)
sys.exit(p.returncode)
```